# round decimal to lowest float with steps

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding

I'm trying to round decimals to lowest float with steps in python. For example, if the step is 0.01, 0.287 should be rounded to 0.28, and 0.29 should be kept.
The issue is that my function prints 0.28 when i round 0.29:

```
int(0.29/0.01)*0.01
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

**EDIT:**

I found a working function for this issue:

```
def round_best(a, step):
if abs(round(a/step)-(a/step))<0.00001:
    return round(a, -decimal.Decimal(str(step)).as_tuple().exponent)
else:
    return ((int(str(a/step).split('.')[0])) * step)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: What does “should be rounded to 0.28, and 0.29 should be kept” mean? Are you asking for two results from one operation?

Comment: Neither .29 nor .01 are representable in the most commonly used floating-point format, IEEE-754 binary64. The closest representable values are 0.289999999999999980015985556747182272374629974365234375 and 0.01000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375. That explains why `int(0.29/.01)` gives 28. Rounding numbers that contain these sorts of errors is problematic, and correct solutions require context—you should explain where these numbers come from, why you need to round them, and what amount of calculation error is tolerable.

Comment: @EricPostpischil please see the edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a step of 0.01 ->
If your number contains aleast 2 decimal places

```
number = 2.9
stab = 0.05
c = ((int(str(number/stab).split('.')[0])) * stab)
print(c)
```

Finally this would work

Comment: 2.827 should be rounded to 2.82 as i'm looking for the lower float!

Comment: will all the number be of at least two decimal points

Comment: sorry but the step can be 0.05. So for 2.827 the result should be 2.8 and for 2.85 it will be 2.85.

Comment: 0.8, 0.9 all of them

Comment: it deosnt work for 2.9. it gives 2.85 instead of 2.9!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222451/discussion-between-divyessh-and-valometrics-com).

Comment: Just use the round() function.

Comment: @LevB please read the whole question as well as comments, He wanted to find floor and that to as per differents stabs so 2.87 ina stab of 0.1 shall be 2.8 not 2.9